# Get width of fields from string

Tags: bash

I have the sgring below for which I'm trying to get the width of each field (counting the spaces) and store it in a variable
in format `pos = "len1 len2 len3... lenN"`

```
string="AB        BC_DEF     GH   I       "
```

Then fields lengths would be

- 1st field: `AB`         with length of 10
- 2nd field: `BC_DEF`      with length of 11
- 3rd field `GH`    with length of 5
- 4th field `I`        with length of 8

My current attempt is like below

```
string="AB        BC_DEF     GH   I       " 
words=("AB" "BC_DEF" "GH" "I")

for w in "${words[@]}"; do
    pos="$pos $(echo "$string" | grep -bo "$w" | sed 's/:.*$//')"
done

$ echo $pos
0 10 21 26
```

But is getting me the beginning of each "word". Is there a way to get easely what I try to do? Thanks

Comment: `2nd field: BC DEF     ` Why aren't these two "fields"? What is a field? Please explain the protocol rules.

Comment: I've edited. It was a typo. These are headers in a big file without spaces in headers. Intead of spaces in headers, are `_`. Thanks

Comment: Is the number of fields always 4?

Comment: @Cyrus No, the number of field can change and the width too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ <<<"$string" awk 'BEGIN{FS=ORS;ORS=OFS}{gsub(/ +/,"&\n")}{for(i=1;i<NF;++i) print length($i)}'                                              
10 11 5 8 
$ <<<"$string" sed 's/ \+/&\n/g' | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=OFS}{print length}'
10 11 5 8 0
$ <<<"$string" awk 'BEGIN{RS=" +";ORS=OFS}RT{print length+length(RT)}'
10 11 5 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Eat the string one token at a time. You could for example use bash, or anything else, express your tokenization as a regex or just a loop. For example:

```
string="AB        BC_DEF     GH   I       " 
while ((${#string})); do
    [[ "$string" =~ ^([^ ]* *)(.*) ]]
    echo "elem: '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
    string=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
done
```

Will output:

```
elem: 'AB        '
elem: 'BC_DEF     '
elem: 'GH   '
elem: 'I       '
```

I.e. "eat" from the input tokens from the beginning to back.

Well, you could just:

```
string="AB        BC_DEF     GH   I       "
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(printf "%s" "$string" | sed 's/[^ ]* */&\x00/g')
declare -p arr
```

But pure bash will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do `echo $arr[n]` I get `AB [n]`. Which variable would contain the widths? my goal is to get this output `10 11 5 8` as content of variable $pos,

Comment: The array, arr contains the widths. Consider reading a bash tutorial, introduction to bash arrays, and check your scripts with shellcheck. `$arr[n]` That is not how you reference an array element number `n`, and the expansion is not quoted. `is to get this output` Sure, after you get the tokens getting the length of strings in bash should be an easy google search.